# StaggeredGridLayoutManager is loading one item on left and the rest on the right

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the StaggeredGridLayoutManager but facing a weird issue.
Once I'm opening the fragment with the Recyclerview, item load but isn't placed at the right place. Like I have two columns (A and B) and 4 items.
Item 1 is in A
Item 2-3-4 are in B
But if I refresh the fragment then 3 switch to A and everything is fine.
I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is the code where I define the layoutManager and the rest of the code is obliviously open source.

https://github.com/Martichou/Lionwayt/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/martichou/me/lionwayt/fragments/HomeProfileFragment.kt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by using this layoutManager

```
val lm = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        lm.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```

Comment: It is not visible after adding gapStrategy GAP_HANDLING_NONE.